# SQL Server - Create Additional Database File for New Schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a change script for some upcoming changes. We're adding a new schema to the database and our client wants the new schema to make use of a new database file.

How do I, in T-SQL, create the new file and assign the new objects within the schema to use the new file?

We're using SQL Sever 2012.

Comment: Please have a look here: [Create different filegroup for different Schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693290/create-different-filegroup-for-different-schema)

Answer (score 1):

You can [create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb522469.aspx) a new filegroup, make it `DEFUALT`, create all schema objects and switch `DEFAULT` filegroup back. If at any later point you would need to add objects to that schema, you can explicitly specify filegroup through `ON filegroup` clause for each object in [create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) statement or temporarily switch `DEFUALT` filegroup.

Alternatively you can explicitly specify `ON filegroup` for each object of this client's schema.

Comment: I have the file groups created OK, but not the physical files. How do I specify which physical file to use for a file group?

Comment: [ALTER DATABASE database_name ADD FILE <filespec> TO FILEGROUP { filegroup_name }](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb522469.aspx)